# Can a function take an undefined number of arguments?

Tags: php

Is it possible to have a function in PHP which takes 1 or more numbers and returns their sum ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing Undefined Arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151053/accessing-undefined-arguments)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can make use of the function [func_num_args](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) and [func_get_arg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php) as:

```
function sum() {
        for($i=0,$sum=0;$i<func_num_args();$i++) {
                $sum += func_get_arg($i);
        }
        return $sum;
}
```

And call the function as:

```
echo sum(1);       // prints 1
echo sum(1,2);     // prints 3
echo sum(1,2,3);   // prints 6
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is

```
function sum() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    return array_sum($args);
}

echo sum(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

You can also further abstract this notion to be able to wrap any array function

```
function mapargs() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    return call_user_func(array_shift($args), $args);
}

echo mapargs('array_sum', 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

or make a currified varargs mapper-wrapper out of it

```
function mapify($func) {
    return function() use($func) {
        $a = func_get_args();
        return call_user_func($func, $a);
    };
}

$sum = mapify('array_sum');
echo $sum(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Very cool answer. `function() use($func) {}` Is this the new lambda stuff in 5.3?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [func_get_args( ).](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)
It returns an array containing all arguments passed to the function, basically exactly what you want.

You can use [func_num_args( )](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) to directly receive the number of the arguments.

However note that it is, in most cases, better to just pass an array to the function instead. The above functions are thought for special cases where it is easier and/or more readable to not create and pass arrays directly to the function.

This trivial, rather unrealistic, example shows the advantages:

```
// By passing an array to the function
function add1( $nums )
{
 $res = 0;
 foreach( $nums as $n )
 {
        $res += $n;
 }
 return $res;
}
add1( array( 1, 2, 3, 4 ) );

// Using func_get_args()
function add2( )
{
 $res = 0;
 foreach( func_get_args() as $n )
 {
        $res += $n;
 }
 return $res;
}
add2( 1, 2, 3, 4 );
```

`add2()` is clearly easier to use and the calls to it are more readable in this case.

The solution above is general on how to get a function to take an arbitrary amount of arguments. If your problem is really only about adding up some numbers, use `array_add()` as the other answers pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

just use [array_sum()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php):

```
$sum = array_sum($arrayOfValues);
```

Answer (score 3):

what about just passing array?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. We use arrays for that.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

And also php has a array_sum function too:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php

```
<?php
$a = array(2, 4, 6, 8);
echo "sum(a) = " . array_sum($a) . "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

In PHP 5.6 and later you will be able to do it this way:

```
function sum(...$nums) {
  for($i=0,$sum=0;$i<count($nums);$i++) {
    $sum += $nums[$i];
  }
  return $sum;
}
```

Or, simplified using foreach:

```
function sum(...$nums) {
  $sum=0;
  foreach($nums as $num) {
    $sum += $num;
  }
  return $sum;
}
```

Source: [PHP Manual: Function arguments](http://php.net/manual/es/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
<?php
function sum(){
  $args = func_get_args();
  $sum = 0;
  foreach($args as $arg){
    if(is_numeric($arg)){
      $sum += $arg;
    }
  }
  return $sum;
}

echo sum().'<br/>
'.sum(1,2,3,"4", "5.63");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sum($args) {
  $total = 0;
  foreach($args as $num) {
    $total += $num;
  }
  return $total;
}
```

`$args` is an array, which you might create like this:

`$args = array(3, 4, 5, 6);`

Comment: That's what array_sum() is for.

Comment: I prefer using "function sum(array $args) {}" as it removes the need to check if you really got an array.

Answer (score 0):

Functional way:

```
function fold($step, $acc, $nums) {
  $val = array_pop($nums);
  if (isset($val)) {
    $acc = call_user_func($step, $val, $acc);
    return fold($step, $acc, $nums);
  } else {
    return $acc;
  }
}

function add($a, $b) {
  return $a + $b;
}

function sum($args) {
  return fold('add',0,$args);
}
```